# How is it possible to update this method that it allows a user to only guess 5 times?

Tags: java, counter, do-while

Is a do..while loop with an incremented counter how you would only allow user to guess 5 times? Attempted to do so with the do while but doesn't seem to work...

Or would a for loop be best way to do so?

```
public static void guessRandomNumber() {

        // declare var for user guess and default to zero
        int userGuess = 0;
        // declare boolean relating to if number is valid
        boolean validNumber = false;
        // declare boolean relating to if guess is correct
        boolean correctGuess = false;
        // declaring int equal to return value from generateRandomNumber();
        int secretNumber = generateRandomNumber();

        //Do while loop that runs until user guesses correctly
        do {

            //Do while loop that runs until a valid entry is given (i.e. an integer)
            do {

                try {
                    //do while loop ensuring that user guess is between 1 and 10
                    do {

                        // Get user guess (between 1 and 10)
                        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 10...");
                        userGuess = scanner.nextInt();

                        if (userGuess < 1 || userGuess > 10) {
                            validNumber = false;
                            System.out.println("Please Ensure number is between 1 and 10");
                        }else {
                            validNumber=true;
                        }
                    } while (!validNumber);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    //Print error message
                    System.out.println("Sorry invalid entry...");
                    // Flush scanner
                    scanner.next();
                    validNumber = false;
                }
            } while (!validNumber);

            //If else statement that outputs a message informing user if guess correct
            if (userGuess == secretNumber) {

                System.out.println("Guess correct, well done!");
                correctGuess = true;

            } else {

                System.out.println("Sorry guess Incorrect please try again!");
                correctGuess = false;

            }

        } while (!correctGuess);

    }// end ofGuessRandomNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

just add a counter `numberOfGuesses` and change the while loop like this:

```
do {
   // do stuff and increment numberOfGuesses

} while (!correctGuess && numberOfGuesses < 5);
```

Also I don't see why you would need 3 while loops for this task. One would be enough, you can check all conditions in one.

Comment: Where would I add a message to the user that they have guesed more than five times? Would this be outside loop? thanks

Comment: yes outside the loop you can check if `correctGuess` is `true`. If it is `false` you know the loop terminated because there were more than 5 guesses (and not because they guessed correctly) and you can output a message.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a counter as follows and you can continue up to 5 and break after that.

```
int counter=1;

while(counter<=5){ // while loop will runs 5 times.
  // do your task
  counter++; // up your counter value.

}
```

You can have some idea from this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a counter, which you decrement on each `validNumber`, and in the outer loop check that this is non zero.